# Get existing instance of List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I've inherited a bloated project that uses a huge class as an in-memory database:

```
public class Database
{
    public class Parameter1
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter1Value> paramValues;
    }

    public class Parameter2
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter2Value> paramValues;
    }

    public class Parameter1Value
    {
        public string Value { get; set;}
        public Parameter parameter { get; set;}
    }

    public class Parameter2Value
    {
        public int Value { get; set;}
        public Parameter2 parameter { get; set;}
    }

    public List<Parameter1> parameter1List { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter2> parameter2List { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a generic method that creates instances of Parameter1 or Parameter2 (see below) and should add those to their respective lists, but I don't know how to use those types to get the parameter1List or parameter2List instances from my Database class. The Database class holds only one List`<T>` property for each defined type.  Is this possible?

This is the generic method used to create instances:

```
public static Database Add<T>(this Database database, string code, string label) where T : new()
{
    T itemToCreate = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    itemToCreate.Code = code;
    itemToCreate.Label = label;
    var listForItem = database.GetList<T>; // This is the missing functionality
    listForItem.Add(itemToCreate);
    return database;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using interfaces and generic constraints.

Create an interface to represent a generic parameter class and add members to the interface as required:

```
public interface IParameter { ... }
```

And an interface to represent a list of parameters:

```
public interface IParameterList<TParameter> where TParameter : IParameter
{
    List<TParameter> ParameterList { get; set; }
}
```

Have the `Database` and `Parameter` classes implement these new interfaces:

```
public class Parameter1 : IParameter

public class Parameter2 : IParameter

public class Database : IParameterList<Parameter1>, IParameterList<Parameter2>
{
    List<Parameter1> IParameterList<Parameter1>.ParameterList { get => parameter1List; set => parameter1List = value; }
    List<Parameter2> IParameterList<Parameter2>.ParameterList { get => parameter2List; set => parameter2List = value; }

    ...
}
```

Add a `where TParameter : IParameter` constraint to your generic Parameter factory function, and have the factory function require an argument of type `IParameterList<TParameter>` which is an instance of the `Database` class. This satisfies the compiler that the `Database` class owns a list of `TParameter`. Now we just do `db.ParameterList.Add(r)` to add our new parameter to the correct list.

```
public static TParameter CreateParameter<TParameter>(IParameterList<TParameter> db) where TParameter : IParameter, new()
{
    var r = new TParameter(); // This is the generic function you mentioned. Do stuff here to create your Parameter class.
    db.ParameterList.Add(r); // Add the newly created parameter to the correct list
    return r;
}
```

---

Code dump (full working version after I picked up your edit which added the generic factory function):

```
public class Parameter1 : IParameter
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter1Value> paramValues;
}

public class Parameter2 : IParameter
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter2Value> paramValues;
}

public class Parameter1Value
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Parameter parameter { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter2Value
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Parameter2 parameter { get; set; }
}

public class Database : IParameterList<Parameter1>, IParameterList<Parameter2>
{
    // Note: Setters for the List properties probably not needed here or in IParameterList as with the following code we instantiate them at class construction time and, in this MCVE at least, there are no further assignments
    public List<Parameter1> parameter1List { get; set; } = new List<Parameter1>();
    public List<Parameter2> parameter2List { get; set; } = new List<Parameter2>();

    List<Parameter1> IParameterList<Parameter1>.ParameterList { get => parameter1List; set => parameter1List = value; }
    List<Parameter2> IParameterList<Parameter2>.ParameterList { get => parameter2List; set => parameter2List = value; }

    public static TParameter Add<TParameter>(IParameterList<TParameter> db, string code, string label) where TParameter : IParameter, new()
    {
        var itemToCreate = new TParameter();
        itemToCreate.Code = code;
        itemToCreate.Label = label;
        db.ParameterList.Add(itemToCreate); // Add the newly created parameter to the correct list
        return itemToCreate;
    }
}

public interface IParameter
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Label { get; set; }
}

public interface IParameterList<TParameter> where TParameter : IParameter
{
    List<TParameter> ParameterList { get; set; }
}

// Testing:
void Main()
{
    var db = new Database();
    Database.Add<Parameter1>(db, "hello", "hello2");
    Database.Add<Parameter1>(db, "hello", "hello2");
    Database.Add<Parameter2>(db, "hello", "hello2");
    Console.WriteLine($"P1 count (should be 2): {db.parameter1List.Count()}; P2 count (should be 1): {db.parameter2List.Count}");
}
```

Output:

> P1 count (should be 2): 2; P2 count (should be 1): 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which acquires the target list using generics and reflection:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(this Database dataBase) where T : new()
{
    return dataBase.GetType()
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(List<T>))
      .Select(x => (List<T>)x.GetValue(dataBase))
      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

---

Credit: Michael Randall in the comments